# How is dipole moment of ammonia less than sulphur dioxide?

Tags: covalent-compounds, dipole

Sulphur dioxide has only two bonds at 180º so shouldn't the dipole moment of molecule be 0 and as ammonia has 1 lone pair so it's dipole can't be 0 so how Sulphur dioxide has more dipole moment than ammonia?

Comment: Sulphur dioxide isn't linear - also has a lone pair on central atom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you visit [this page](https://www.quora.com/Is-SO2-a-dipolar-molecule). Sulfur dioxide is almost always in [this form](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-582be9a3ccf0211945cc6e74c1ac912d). Two Oxygens are more electronegative than a single Nitrogen and also S-O bond is longer than N-H bond, though the dipole moment of S-O is more than N-H and despite the lone pair on S, SO2 has a greater dipole moment than NH3.